# Elasticserach not creating the Indice for new pipeline via logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

I have set-up a ELK but I see elasticsearch not creating the Index and unable to upload the data, Service Elasticsearch and Logstash both are running..

Below is the details.. However I do not see anything on he logs.

Elastic config:

```
[root@aruba-elk2 rm_logs]# cat /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
# Elasticserach config
#########################
cluster.name: log-cohort-test
node.name: aruba-elk2
node.master: true
path:
    data: /elk/lib/elasticsearch
    logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
bootstrap.system_call_filter: False
[root@aruba-elk2 rm_logs]#
[root@aruba-elk2 rm_logs]#
```

LOGSTASH COnfig:

```
    [root@aruba-elk2 rm_logs]# cat /etc/logstash/logstash.yml
    path.data: /var/lib/logstash
    path.logs: /var/log/logstash

[root@aruba-elk2 rm_logs]# cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash-syslog.conf
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/elk/rm_logs/*.txt" ]
    type => "rmlog"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "rmlog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:hostname},%{DATE:date},%{HOUR:hour1}:%{MINUTE:minute1},%{NUMBER}-%{WORD},%{USER:user},%{USER:user2} %{NUMBER:pid} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:number1} %{NUMBER:number2} %{DATA} %{HOUR:hour2}:%{MINUTE:minute2} %{HOUR:hour3}:%{MINUTE:minute3} %{GREEDYDATA:command},%{PATH:path}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
   }
 }
}

output {
        if [type] == "rmlog" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["aruba-elk2:9200"]
                manage_template => false
                index => "rmlog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                #document_type => "messages"
  }
 }
}
```

Input data Source:

```
[root@aruba-elk2 rm_logs]# cd /elk/rm_logs/
[root@aruba-elk2 rm_logs]# ls -ltrh | head
total 2.6M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  558 Jan 11 11:27 dbxchw092.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  405 Jan 11 11:27 dbxtx220.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  241 Jan 11 11:27 dbxcvm139.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  455 Jan 11 11:27 dbxcnl038.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  230 Jan 11 11:27 dbxchw052.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  143 Jan 11 11:27 dbxtx222.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  577 Jan 11 11:27 dbxtx224.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  274 Jan 11 11:27 dbxcvm082.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  281 Jan 11 11:27 dbxcsb003.txt
```

Sample of above data file:

```
testhost-in2,19/01/11,06:34,04-mins,arnav,arnav 2427 0.1 0.0 58980 580 ? S 06:30 0:00 rm -rf /test/ehf/users/arnav-090119-184844,/dv/ehf/users/arnav-090119-
testhost-in2,19/01/11,06:40,09-mins,arnav,arnav 2427 0.1 0.0 58980 580 ? S 06:30 0:00 rm -rf /dv/ehf/users/arnav-090119-184844,/dv/ehf/users/arnav-090119-\
testhost-in2,19/01/11,06:45,14-mins,arnav,arnav 2427 0.1 0.0 58980 580 ? S 06:30 0:01 rm -rf /
```

LOGS:

Logstash logs:

```
[root@aruba-elk2 logstash]# cat logstash-plain.log
[2019-01-12T23:48:31,653][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.5.4"}
[2019-01-12T23:48:34,959][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>48, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2019-01-12T23:48:35,374][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://aruba-elk2:9200/]}}
[2019-01-12T23:48:35,588][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://aruba-elk2:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://aruba-elk2:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused"}
[2019-01-12T23:48:35,608][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//aruba-elk2:9200"]}
[2019-01-12T23:48:36,063][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"/var/lib/logstash/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_076330d5fd2c2b811bc1960a3d0547be", :path=>["/elk/rm_logs/*.txt"]}
[2019-01-12T23:48:36,095][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x424bb675 run>"}
[2019-01-12T23:48:36,155][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2019-01-12T23:48:36,156][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2019-01-12T23:48:36,542][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2019-01-12T23:48:40,796][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://aruba-elk2:9200/"}
[2019-01-12T23:48:40,855][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2019-01-12T23:48:40,859][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
```

Elasticsearch LOGS:

```
[root@aruba-elk2 elasticsearch]# cat gc.log.0.current| tail
2019-01-13T00:13:29.280+0530: 1237.781: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002681 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000316 seconds
2019-01-13T00:13:31.281+0530: 1239.782: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003670 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000586 seconds
2019-01-13T00:13:32.281+0530: 1240.782: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003134 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000708 seconds
2019-01-13T00:13:37.282+0530: 1245.783: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004663 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001315 seconds
2019-01-13T00:13:51.284+0530: 1259.785: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004230 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000691 seconds
2019-01-13T00:13:57.286+0530: 1265.787: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0008421 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002697 seconds
2019-01-13T00:13:58.287+0530: 1266.787: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004467 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000706 seconds
2019-01-13T00:14:11.288+0530: 1279.789: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004702 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001105 seconds
2019-01-13T00:14:18.289+0530: 1286.790: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004123 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000750 seconds
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you cat the elasticsearch log instead of the gc one?

Comment: @Val, thanks for your revert.  there is no logs only pointer I see is `sincedb_path` , looks like its mandatory to mention in new Version of it 6.5 So, as soon I defined `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`  in the logstash.conf  it started working and created the Index , But its really awkward.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!